# Find substring in Javascript and prepend/append some characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Imagine I have the following multi-line Javascript string:

> school
>
> apple
>
> ~carrot
>
> dog

I want to take any line that starts with "~" and replace it with "#(contents of line)#". So in this example I want to find "~carrot" and replace it with "#carrot#".

I'm trying to come up with a solution using regular expressions but can't figure out a way to replace some matched string with a modified version of itself (with the prepended/appended characters.)

Any help would be appreciated, hoping one example will turn on the lightbulb...

Comment: Is "carrot" a constant string that can be hardcoded or the contents of a variable?

Comment: And what exactly do you want to mach? Lines starting with `~`? You have to provide some more information. What makes `~carrot` so special that you want to replace it?

Comment: Sorry, yes carrot is a variable and yes I want to replace any lines that start with "~" with "#(contents of line)#". Thanks!

Comment: Carrot is just an example, I would not know what it actually was in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`thestring.replace(/~(\w+)/g, "#$1#");`

The parentheses "capture" the word (`\w+`) and the `$1` in the result references what's captured.

Answer (score -1):

It's really easy. Suppose you have your string in OldString

```
var OldString = "school apple  ~carrot dog";

var myNewString = OldString.replace(/~carrot/, "#carrot#");

document.write("Old string =  " + OldString); 
document.write("<br />New string = " + myNewString);
```

Hope it helps