# How to add letters / words / characters to a special word in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Let us consider we have a string **str** and a function **addify()** and we can do something like this with it :

```
 var str = "I am @java";
 console.log(addify(str, "script");
 //=> I am @javascript
```

So, you may understand what happened ! The **addify()** finds all the words with the special character **@** and then adds our desired words or letter or any character to it. Another example :

```
  var str = "I wrote a @s in @javas";
  console.log(addify(str, " cript");
  //=> I wrote a @script in @javascript
```

So, can anyone teach me how to make the **addify()** function ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I could teach you, but did you take any look at the [string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) yourself?

Comment: @Bergi I tried to make the function with regex, but I could't because I don't have much knowledge of regex.

Comment: @Bergi Let me look

Comment: Regex would be one of the shortest solutions, indeed. Can you show us what you tried so that we can see what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Find substring in Javascript and prepend/append some characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056982/find-substring-in-javascript-and-prepend-append-some-characters)

StackOverflow to the rescue!

At the provided link you can find a regex example on how you can identify a special character within a provided string and then edit the result using the string `.replace()` method...

Quick breakdown of the regex: find the `(\w+)` word after the string `@` which is then represented as `$1` as the second parameter in the string .`replace()` method where you can modify the string into a new format.

Bonus points: this will only find instances where the string being searched is connected to another word.  If you targeted identifier (`@`) exists alone, then it will not update a blank space.

```js
function addify( str, ending ){
  return str.replace(/@(\w+)/g, `@$1${ending}`);
}

console.log( addify( 'i like @cheese', 'burgers' ) );
console.log( addify( 'party @ my place', 'not!' ) );
```